# Access class props inside scroll addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to position fix by passing the `fixed` prop from state but I am not able to `setState` inside `handleScroll` function. I am not sure how to access state inside the function.

```
class App extends Component {

  state = { fixed: false }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll(e) {
    let scrollTop = e.srcElement.body.scrollTop;
    (scrollTop > 0) ? this.setState({ fixed: true }) : this.setState({ fixed: false });
  }

  render() {
    // grab steps
    const { steps } = this.props;
    const { fixed } = this.state;
    const { scrollToStep } = this;

    return ce('div', { className:'allTheSteps' },
      ce(pagination, { steps, fixed }),
      Object.values(steps).map((step, i) =>
        ce(Steps, { step, key: v4(), i }),
      )
    );
  };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `handleScroll` method:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  ...

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is being executed in the wrong scope. You have to bind it to the right scope. To do this, you can use ES6 arrow functions and your methods should be bound without having to do it manually.
In your example:

```
...
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => this.handleScroll(e));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', (e) => this.handleScroll(e));
    }
...
```